# How to install Excel OLE DB to Windows Server 2008?

Tags: .net, excel, windows-server-2008, oledb

We have a web server running Windows 2008 32-bit.

When we deploy a website that reads from Excel using OLE DB, we got this error

> The 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0'
>   provider is not registered on the
>   local machine.

We don't want to install Microsoft Office on the server. Is there anything else we can do to solve this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install Data Connectivity Components on the server

http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?familyid=7554F536-8C28-4598-9B72-EF94E038C891&displaylang=en